# Is there an equivalent to Stata's testparm function in R?

Tags: r, stata

The R survey package has the function regTermTest which tests for a number of parameters being jointly equal to zero. Stata's testparm takes the "equal" option which tests for the parameters being equal and reports a p-value. I am looking for an equivalent or workaround to mimic that.

Comment: This might help: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59085/how-to-test-for-simultaneous-equality-of-choosen-coefficients-in-logit-or-probit

Comment: Just create a new variable `x3 <- x1-x2` and run with `y ~ x2 +x3`. You should be able to use the estimate for beta as the difference in effects and test versus 0 with either Wald or LRT.  (I think this is probably a duplicate question.)